# Autolayout heights proportionally but with upper limit constraint

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder, autolayout

[image: UI Sheet for design]

I am trying to use Autolayout and only Interface Builder to produce the following scene with 2 views in all four iPhone devices. As the picture indicates I would like that view2 (the bottom view) be no smaller than 45points on a iPhone 4 and never get higher than 65 points. View2 does not have to be exactly the indicated number of points in the attached image if for example your idea for a solution uses some kind of proportions.

Comment: Constraint view2's height equals to 1/10 height of its superview with priority 999, and view2's height less than 65 points with priority 1000.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

horizontal constraints are obvious. Vertical constraints:

- view1 top to navigation bar bottom
- view2 bottom to superview bottom
- view1 bottom equals to view 2 top
- aspect ratio (~1/10) constraint between view 2 and view1 with high (=750) priority
- height of view 2 is greater than 45 with required (=1000) priority
- height of view 2 is less than 65 with required (=1000) priority

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Can you please elaborate on the aspect ratio constrain. I did not know you can have one on 2 views

Comment: @darbid `view2.height` equals to `view1.height` with multiplier of 10.

Comment: Perfect kovpas I am trying it right now.  Thank you.

Comment: I have this working for height but not width, for the exact same view and exact same set up. >= constraint for min height, <= constraint for max height at priority 1000, and a proportional width (90%) constraint with priority 999. It seems to ignore the proportional width, and I end up with the view set to its minimum width.